# How can I keep file name to variable from this code

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

readLBL.sh

```
  #!/bin/bash
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        echo "Text read from file: $line"
    done < "$1"
```

When I run this shell script in Terminal and I have to insert file name for run it

Example :

```
./readLBL.sh science.txt
```

output :

58050364;Tom Jones

58050365;Marry Jane

how can i keep "science.txt" into some variable like `a = "science.txt"`

Comment: You have it in `$1`

Comment: assign $1 to a variable `a=$1`

Comment: @yoones wow thanks ! i got it , I'm beginner in shell script .

Answer (score 0):

Use `$1` as this is the argument you are already using to read the file in the first instance.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "Text read from file $1: $line"
done < "$1"
```

Running this gives the following:

```
$ ./readLBL.sh science.txt
Text read from file science.txt: 58050364;Tom Jones
Text read from file science.txt: 58050365;Marry Jane
```

Answer (score 0):

a="science.txt" 
from the Linux command line, will set $a equal to science.txt

If you want this permanent, you could perhaps add it to the bottom of one of your linux profiles. For example add it to the bottom of ~/.bashrc